# How can I randomly generate a number in the range -0.5 and 0.5?

Tags: javascript, random

In javascript how do I randomly generate a number between -0.5 and 0.5? The following only seems to give positive numbers, and no negative numbers.

```
Math.random(-0.15, 0.15)
```

Comment: Did you even look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) ?

Comment: The OP seems to be fairly new to JS. He might not have heard about MDN before now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting MDN on [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random),

> The `Math.random()` function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive)

So, generate random numbers between 0 and 1 and subtract 0.5 from it.

```
Math.random() - 0.5
```

**Note:** `Math.random()` doesn't expect any parameters. So, you cannot specify any range.

---

If you want to generate random numbers between a range, use the [example snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Using_Math.random()) in MDN,

```
// Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

---

**Demo with Range**

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}


function appendToResult(value) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += value + "<br />";
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  appendToResult(getRandomArbitrary(-0.35, 0.35));
}
```

```html
<pre id="result" />
```

This works because, the expression

```
Math.random() * (max - min) + min
```

will be evaluated in the following manner. First,

```
Math.random()
```

will be evaluated to get a random number in the range 0 and 1 and then

```
Math.random() * (max - min)
```

it will be multiplied with the difference between `max` and `min` value. In your case, lets say `max` is `0.35` and `min` is `-0.35`. So, `max - min` becomes `0.7`. So, `Math.random() * (max - min)` gives a number in the range `0` and `0.7` (because even if `Math.random()` produces `1`, when you multiply it with `0.7`, the result will become `0.7`). Then, you do

```
Math.random() * (max - min) + min
```

So, for your case, that basically becomes,

```
Math.random() * (0.35 - (-0.35)) + (-0.35)
(Math.random() * 0.7) - 0.35
```

So, if `(Math.random() * 0.7)` generates any value greater than `0.35`, since you subtract `0.35` from it, it becomes some number between `0` and `0.35`. If `(Math.random() * 0.7)` generates a value lesser than `0.35`, since you subtract `0.35` from it, it becomes a number between `-0.35` and `0`.

Comment: Thanks all, super helpful. 

What if I wanted to get a number between -0.35 and 0.35 ?  (edit) Oh got it, I could use that function :D  Wait, I don't quite get the math though...  o.O!

Comment: @AgentZebra I included a small demo and some explanation of how the math works here, please check and let me know if you have more questions about it.

Comment: Thanks so much thefourtheye, super helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Math.random()` to get a number between 0 and 1 then reduce `.5` to set the lower and upper bounds

```
Math.random() - .5
```